# label over label overwriting , while displaying the health lable in cocos2d android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I have to display the palyers lifes in my game. every time the player hits the wrong enemy the lifes decrease.the default lifes are 5.

My code is as follows

first I declare this in my gamelayer

```
static int lifes=5;
CCLabel _lifes;
```

then a method as follows at bottom of the code

```
public void showLable(CCLabel _lifes){


     if(_lifes != null){
            this.removeChild(_lifes,true);
        }

     _lifes = CCLabel.makeLabel("" + lifes, "Verdana", 20);
        _lifes.setColor(ccColor3B.ccbrown);
        _lifes.setPosition(winSize.width/2,(winSize.height/2));
        addChild(_lifes,3)
    }
```

then I wrote this condition where the player hits the wrong enemy

```
lifes--;
showLable(_lifes);
```

1) everything works fine, the lable is displayed and label gets decreased but the label does not show up until the player hits the wrong enemy, as you see I gave default value as 5, the label shows up after the player hits wrong enemy ie, from 4.

2) Another major problem is the label displayed is displaying without removing the previous value. For ex. the lifes are 5 as default. 5 is displayed when when game starts. when the life decreases the lifes value should be 4, So here in my game the 4 is placed on 5 itself. 
And then the lifes are placed on the same number as 3 or 2 or 1. All the nuumbers show on each other. Now I think you understand me

thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you are calling `showLable(_lifes);` at the start of your game after its initialized, so the label show up with the value 5.  Do you ?  for the 2) I really don't get it sry :/

Comment: No, 5 is not at all displayed, it directly starts with 4. In total 5 lifes, when one life is gone ,the label shows up as 4( which means 4 lifes left). What I want is, 5 to be displayed as default from the game start itself. Thank You

Comment: Now i got it, i just have to write    showLable(_lifes); at the start of the game. But I am still suffering the second problem..Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check that your are calling  `showLable(_lifes);` at the start of your game after its initialized, so the label show up with the value 5.

2) I'm not really sure about it but **CCLabel** should extends a **CCSprite** and thus have a setVisible method.
you may try something like :

```
    if(_lifes != null){
        _lifes.setVisible(false);
        this.removeChild(_lifes,true);
    }
```

I only found the c++ api reference version : 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d4/de7/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_sprite.html

Comment: for the 2) one ,That didnt work...I think there should be some method to clear the old value of the LIFES and update to new value........

Comment: well you shouldn't need to clear to old values since you are recreating a new label from scratch...    maybe you can avoid recreating and change the value  ( isn't there a 'setString' method ?

Comment: if(life!= null){
this.removeChild(life ,true);
}

Comment: yeah, since it didn't work i was thinking about other way to go sry I couldn't help.

Comment: I got the answer. just replace the lifes--; to lifes=lifes-1;